# GROUP BY except for specific values that need to be added up

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, aggregate-functions

I have a table like this:

```
id | type
---+------
1  | plane
2  | plane
3  | ferry
4  | ferry
5  | car
6  | car
7  | bus
8  | train
```

We can count the rows for each type:

```
select type, count(*) from transport group by type;

type  | count
------+------
plane | 2
ferry | 2
car   | 2
bus   | 1
train | 1
```

This works, but notice how the last three types - `car`, `bus`, `train` - are ground transport (while `plane` is air and `ferry` is sea). What I really want is:

```
type   | count
-------+------
plane  | 2
ferry  | 2
car    | 4
```

I could sum up the counts at the application level, but is this feasible in SQL? Thank you.

Comment: It appears you need to create some groups and map the types to a group name, then aggregate using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case`  expression to reassign buses and trains to the car group:

```
select
    case when type in ('bus', 'train') then 'car' else type end as new_type,
    count(*)
from transport
group by new_type
```